# How to Load Json in Endless Recycler Veiw with Retrofit

Tags: android, json, pagination, retrofit2

I try to implement Endless Recycler View with my Json Response .

This is My Json Response [Link](http://www.aparat.com/etc/api/categoryvideos)

I Generate my models with jsonschema2pojo.org and I load the data in my recyclerview successfully .

But I need to implement endless recycler view :

This is my RecyclerAdapter :

```
public class AparatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AparatAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Categoryvideo> categoryVideos;

    //=============================constructor
    public AparatAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Categoryvideo> categoryVideos) {
        this.context = context;
        this.categoryVideos = categoryVideos;
    }
    //=============================viewholder
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView txtTitle ,txtCount ,txtSender ,txtDate;
        private ImageView imgRow;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title_row);
            txtCount = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_count_dynamic_row);
            txtSender = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_sender_dynamic_row);
            txtDate = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_date_dynamic_row);
            imgRow = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_row);
        }
    }

    //================================oncreateviewholder

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    //================================= onbindviewholder

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.txtTitle.setText(categoryVideos.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.txtCount.setText(categoryVideos.get(position).getVisitCnt().toString());
        holder.txtSender.setText(categoryVideos.get(position).getSenderName());
        holder.txtDate.setText(categoryVideos.get(position).getSdate().toString());
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(categoryVideos.get(position).getSmallPoster())
                .into(holder.imgRow);
    }

    //==================================getitemcount

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoryVideos.size();
    }
}
```

And This is the activity where i load the json in that with retrofit :

```
public class SargarmiActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private AparatAdapter adapter;
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    private ArrayList<Categoryvideo> categoryvideos;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sargarmi);
        initViews();
    }
    //=================================================

    private void initViews() {
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_sargarmi);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(SargarmiActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        sendRequest();
    }

    //=================================================
    private void sendRequest() {
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(layoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
                loadMore();
            }
        });
        getData();
    }



    //=======================================================
    private void getData() {
        //1
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://www.aparat.com/etc/api/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        //2
        ApiInterface request = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

        //3
        Call<JSONResponse> call = request.getJsonResponse();

        //4
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
                    categoryvideos = new ArrayList<>(jsonResponse.getCategoryvideos());
                    adapter = new AparatAdapter(SargarmiActivity.this, categoryvideos);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SargarmiActivity.this, "Error darim else onresponse", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(SargarmiActivity.this, "Error darim onFailure()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    //=============== Load more Endless =====================
    private void loadMore() {

    }
}
```

As you can see in [json](http://www.aparat.com/etc/api/categoryvideos) my pagination url embed in ui object . and i don't know what should i write in the loadmore() method in my activity.

Answer (score 0):

When you download the initial load of categoryvideos, there is also an elementcalled: pagingForward. This contains the url for you to download the next 20 items.

So what you want to do is:

1. When downloading the first videos, fetch the pagingForward value
   and store this somewhere.
2. When you call loadMore() you make another download with Retrofit
   with the url.
3. Retrofit will download the objects and you will get another
   pagingForward url that will then point to the next 20 items.
4. This can keep on going until there are no more objects to fetch
   (Not sure how the API respons then, you need to check with the
   persons who wrote the API)